# box-sizing: border-box; is not properly working

Tags: html, css

I am trying to learn css and html5 and got stuck at form . I got a code from w3schools that if i want to make form at rectangular in shape i should use box-sizing: border-box in my css code but its happening here 
Can you please have a take a look on my code :

```css
#modal_form input[type=text] {
    width: 320px;
 height: 40px;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    -o-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<form id="modal_form">
        <input type="text" name="name" class="name" placeholder="Full Name"><br>
       <input type="text" name="email" class="email" placeholder="Email address"><br>
        <input type="text" name="phone" class="email" placeholder="Phone no"><br>
       <input type="text" name="website" class="email" placeholder="Your Website"><br>
        <input type="text" name="question" class="email" placeholder="Your Question??">
        <center><input  class="form-control" type="submit" name="contact" id="submit" value="Send Message"></center> 
      </form>
```

Here its coming properly but in my code its coming like this :

[image: Preview]

May be i am using old template with earlier release of bootstrap and other , So what would be alternative

Thanks in advance@!!!

Comment: I'm not sure if you mistaken `box-sizing` for something else. This property is for what should be considered when using `width` and `height`: Should _padding_ and _border_ size be included (`border-box`) or the content only (`content-box`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`box-sizing` is used to manipulate the collision-box of elements, not the visual shape.

What you are looking for might be `border-radius` which I think bootstrap applies to your inputs. You should be able to fix it by adding `border-radius: 0` to your CSS code. Since here on Stack is no bootstrap the inputs do not render with rounded corners.